# Time to scale-up workerrole's number of azure instances

Tags: azure, scalability

How much time does it take to azure allocate more instances to the workerrole when is set to automatically scale according to average CPU usage? In other words, how much time azure detects that the average CPU usage is above the threshold and allocate new instances to my worker role?

I need that the scalling process takes less than 1 minute to meet the requirements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the scaling process is up to 15 minutes or even more. First of all scaling event have to be determined. And I wouldn't trigger scale event if I don't see scaling conditions steadily for at least 5-10 minutes. Then, when I (you, or the system) trigger scale, the normal package deployment time is required (as minimum) - and this ranges from 5-6 to 15-20 minutes. Time depends on the current load of the datacentre, package size and startup tasks being executed.

Less than 1 minute dynamic scaling reaction is simply not possible in a traditional cloud model (regardless of the vendor). The only way to achieve "1 minute scaling" is to know precisely when you want to scale (schedule) and configure scheduled scale. Then take into account the minimum 5-7 minutes required and configure your schedule time in accordance with this.

Again, if your business model is "less than 1 minute to scale", you shall either just run with more resources than you need, or seriously reconsider that "1 minute" requirement and make it more like "20 minutes to scale".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My service runs a process that demands high processing per request. I don`t know when the client will ask for the service, but when he asks i need to process his request fast. The problem is that, keeping a high processing capacity machine active is expensive, so i wanted to trigger the scale only when the client request the processing. But it seems there is no cloud service that delivers processing capacity as fast as i want. =/ Gonna look for an alternative solution. Thanks, again!

Comment: One more comment. Looking around i found that [digitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com) deploys a new server instance in 55 seconds! The problem is that it only has linux servers and my service is windows based.

Comment: Do you have any other metrics/knowledge about when to scale, not just CPU utilization - which is usually a poor metric to scale on

Comment: Another metric would be to allocate one instance per request. Each new request i would allocate a new instance to it and after the job the instance would be released.

Comment: You might want to look into Azure Functions or AWS Lamba for more on-demand processing power.